# Gradle transitive dependency resolution issue when multiple Maven repos are defined

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I am encountering an issue with respect to resolution of transitive dependencies in presence of multiple maven repos in my gradle file. Here are snapshots of my root  and module gradle files -

Root gradle -

```
allprojects {
repositories {
        maven {
            name 'A'
            url 'someUrl1'
            credentials {
             //
            }
        }

        maven {
            name 'B'
            url 'someUrl2'

            credentials {
                //
            }
        }

}
```

Module level gradle -

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

}

The issue which I am encountering is that every time I perform gradle sync/build, gradle tries to fetch the maven-metadata file for some of the transitive dependencies of above mentioned dependencies from Repo 'B'. All the dependencies are present in Repo 'A'. I am not sure why repo 'B' is being searched for maven-metadata even when 'A' is listed above 'B'.

Weird thing is that it does not cause any build failure as it does end up getting the dependencies from local gradle cache,  but it significantly increases my build time as it makes multiple network calls during each build.

One thing which I noticed is that 11.0.4 version of gms libraries use square brackets i.e. [11.0.4] to mention the version of their dependencies in the POM file.

To root cause the issue, I updated the dependencies to 11.8.0 where the POM files do not use square brackets to mention their dependency versions and the issue went away.

I am not sure why the presence of specific version dependency in POM file would cause this issue.

Below is a snippet of gradle debug logs -

```
23:24:26.977 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4(default).
23:24:26.978 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver] Attempting to resolve version for com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] using repositories [C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository, C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository, C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository, maven, maven2]
23:24:26.978 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] Listing all in file:/C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/[revision]/play-services-analytics-impl-[revision].pom
23:24:26.978 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] using org.gradle.internal.resource.local.FileResourceConnector@24522fcd to list all in file:/C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/
23:24:26.978 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader] parsing maven-metadata: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-analytics-impl\maven-metadata.xml
23:24:26.980 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/11.0.4/play-services-analytics-impl-11.0.4.pom
23:24:26.983 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Metadata file found for module 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.0.4' in repository 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository'.
23:24:26.983 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] Listing all in file:/C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/[revision]/play-services-analytics-impl-[revision].pom
23:24:26.983 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ResourceVersionLister] using org.gradle.internal.resource.local.FileResourceConnector@24522fcd to list all in file:/C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/
23:24:26.984 [INFO] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Creating new cache for metadata-2.36/module-versions, path C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-versions.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@334c9d50
23:24:26.984 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Acquiring file lock for artifact cache (C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2)
23:24:26.989 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\primanda\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
23:24:26.990 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process (pid: 14924, lockId: -9157439162897582946). Pinged owner at port 56301
23:24:26.990 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler] Gradle process at port 56301 confirmed unlock request for lock with id -9157439162897582946.
23:24:26.990 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler] Gradle process at port 56301 confirmed unlock request for lock with id -9157439162897582946.
23:24:27.001 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on artifact cache (C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
23:24:27.001 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache module-versions.bin (C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-versions.bin)
23:24:27.002 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.36\module-metadata.bin)
23:24:27.004 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Using cached module metadata for module 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.0.4' in 'maven'
23:24:27.004 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://someurl2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics-impl/maven-metadata.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is indeed caused by the notation `[11.0.4]` which Gradle interprets as a range and thus triggers dynamic version resolution.

When doing dynamic version resolution, Gradle will search in all the repositories defined in the build script to make sure to have a complete view of all the versions available.
Gradle will then cache locally the retrieved information to improve performance of subsequent builds.

Comment: I suspected this to be the case. But isn't it a bug with gradle itself? Just square brackets shouldn't be interpreted as version ranges

Comment: Feel free to open a defect. But I am afraid that hides some backward compatibility issue from Maven or Ivy handling of ranges.